# Partial Match Index Match Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel

i have formula, that i want to find anything that starts with 80 such as 80E or 80M. formula is here

=INDEX('MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!M:M,MATCH(1,(Corrected!A2='MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!A:A)*("80"&" * "='MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!M:M),0))

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't handle wildcards with the equals operator. You need to use the LEFT text function to extract the first 2 characters from column M to compare to exactly "80":

`=INDEX('MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!M:M,MATCH(1,(Corrected!A2='MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!A:A)*("80"=left('MFX SCR Mains Costs from SAP'!M:M,2)),0))`